# Не срабатывает random при выборе текста

Tags: случайные-числа, setinterval

Постоянно выводится только текст quotes[0], нужно random - quotes[0] или quotes[1]. Прошу помочь иправить код.

```
var quotes=new Array();
quotes[0] = "Сергей оформил товар1."; 
quotes[1] = "Юлия купила товар2.";

var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote=Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1));

function showquote(){
document.getElementById('popupname').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote]
}

function PopUpHide(){
$("#popup1").hide();
}

function timeout_init() {
showquote();
setTimeout("$('#popup1').show()", 3000);
}

function timeout_init1() {
timeout_init();
setTimeout("$('#popup1').hide()", 8000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
PopUpHide();
setInterval(function() { timeout_init1(); }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Igor: Спасибо, но мне нужно с сохранением $('#popup1').show() и hide(), тоесть: ждем 10сек, открывается поп-ап на 3 сек, закрывается через 5 сек. При том текст должен выводится random.

Comment: Вы шутите? Я показал Вам, как сделать, чтобы выводилась случайно выбранная фраза. Ваши попапы и секунды к этому отношения не имеют.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем коде `whichquote` назначается только один раз.

```js
var quotes = [];
quotes[0] = "Сергей оформил товар 1."; 
quotes[1] = "Юлия купила товар 2.";
var q = quotes.length;

function showquote() {
  var whichquote = Math.round(Math.random() * (q - 1));
  document.getElementById('popupname').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote];
}

function timeout_init() {
  showquote();
}

function timeout_init1() {
  timeout_init();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(timeout_init1, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="popupname"></div>
```